# Allow someone start a list workflow but forbid him add item to the list

Tags: workflow, permissions

I have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm. Workflow manager is not installed so I can only use Workflow 2010. I created a list workflow and it seems only users with "contribute" or higher permission can start the workflow. Any way I can forbid visitors update the list while allow he or she start the workflow?

Is it possible or we have some workaround here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "contribute" access rights consists of "add", "modify" and "delete" access rights.
You may try to create a customized access right to allow only "modify", i.e. without "add", nor "delete" access rights.

User who is assigned to this customized access rights would be only able to update the existing entries in the list, so as to trigger a workflow, but not add new entries.

In the workflow, however, I guess, if there's a step to add new entries, it might run into an error.